# Waiting with method execution until a condition is met in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, concurrency, mapkit

I have a `MKMapView` with some annotations added by code representing users sharing their location. I get updates about location changes via websockets and update the corresponding `MKAnnotation`.`coordinate` that represent the annotations in `MKMapView`.

This mostly works fine, I see the users moving on the map. The problem is that when a `MKAnnotation.cooridnate` is updated while the user pans or zooms the map then `MKMapView` crashes saying that a hash table was update while being evaluated. It is basically this problem: [MKMapView crashing if zooming while adding annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13924130/mkmapview-crashing-if-zooming-while-adding-annotations)

Update: Crashes only occur when clustering is enabled, no need to even pan or zoom, just waiting a bit is usually enough.

The recommended solution is not doing anything (like updating `MKAnnotation.cooridnate`  in my case) with `MKMapView` between `regionWillChangeAnimated` and `regionDidChangeAnimated` and I am tryintg to implement this.

The problem is that my data is being received via websockets so I cannot just "stop" listening for the new data between those 2 delegate methods. Theoretically I can but that would mean losing some data which is not a solution.

My idea was that I need some kind of queue that I will use to add my updates to  `MKAnnotation.cooridnate` and will get paused in `regionWillChangeAnimated` and resumed in `regionDidChangeAnimated`.

I tried using `DispatchQueue` in the way described but it locks after a while. I am not sure if it is because of the high amount of operations being added to it or the calls to `suspend` and `resume`. If it does not lock it just crashes the app after a while.

My question is what mechanism will work here?

As stated in the question title, I basically need a way to make some methods wait for a condition, say toggling a flag between `regionWillChangeAnimated` and `regionDidChangeAnimated` that is reliable and can take the load.

Comment: When you get a result back, and you notice that your map is mid-scroll, use a `Queue<AnnotationUpdate>` to enqueue the data. When the user is done scrolling, consume the annotation updates from the queue, and apply them to your `MKAnnotation`s

Comment: Using a `queue` is the basic idea but it gets complicated quickly. After the user stops scrolling I start processing the queue but another data updates might arrive, so I need to add them to the queue also so the order is preserved .. and I am back to something like the mentioned dispatch queue

Comment: I have a few separate questions/thoughts. 1) "because of the high amount of operations being added" why are there so many? it's just 1 update per annotation, no? 2) "calls to suspend and resume" suspend and resume aren't sufficient for your needs. They don't interrupt work items in progress.

Comment: I would make a semaphore to synchronize access to the map. Either the map is "taken" by the user to scroll, or it's "taken" by the background process to update the data. While taken, each of those 2 processes need to wait for the other to finish before it can regain control of the map. To keep the map interactive, each data update should only do a single map annotation, so that the user is never stuck waiting. Whenever the map is taken by the user, you can drain the queue and apply changes one at a time, until the user wants the map again.

Comment: Look at OperationQueue. You can manage dependencies (such as "currently zooming"), and you can cancel them (unlike DispatchQueue)

Comment: “I tried using DispatchQueue in the way described but it locks after a while.” Maybe you can show us what you tried as that’s precisely the approach I would suggest (and did suggest below). And I was unable to get it to lock up, as you suggested here. Maybe you can show us what you tried. It would be great if you could post a simple [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) than manifests this problem without getting into the weeds of your codebase.

Comment: FWIW, I’m having troubles reproducing this crash you describe (e.g. https://www.dropbox.com/s/ttnzvnzfwk8gjwx/animated%20annotations.mov?dl=0 is just short clip, but I tried panning, zooming, etc., and unable to manifest the crash). If you help us reproduce the problem, perhaps we can help you solve the problem.

Comment: My code also uses clustering, not only pins, I will try to create a minimal sample project that crashes

Comment: Yep, I was finally able to manifest your problem when I turned on clustering. Interestingly, while the problem was most easily reproduced with panning and zooming, if I just let the app running, I eventually got this crash without any panning/zooming taking place, without touching the map view at all. But if I turned off clustering (or stop mutating the annotations), I could not reproduce the problem.

Comment: The joy of MapKit ... I experience that too, using a simple queue helps but I guess I will just have to catch and ignore the exception somehow or use a custom clustering library instead

Answer (score 0):

If you want to not perform tasks while a certain condition is met, use a `DispatchQueue` and just `suspend` or `resume` it. And if this is for tasks that should be performed on the main queue, make the main queue the target for this queue that will be suspended and resumed:

```
let annotationChangeQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "...", target: .main)
```

But this begs the question: Under what condition should one should `suspend` and `resume` this queue? It would be reasonable to assume (as that other question you reference does) that one could suspend in `regionWillChangeAnimated` and resume in `regionDidChangeAnimated`. Alas, this appears to be insufficient. You’ll find that even if you make sure to not do any annotation changes until after `regionDidChangeAnimated`, it can still crash. And `MKMapView` doesn’t appear to expose any methods/properties that we can observe to avoid this.

I don’t think there is a proper solution to this problem given that Apple isn’t exposing any property that we could possibly detect when it’s safe to mutate our annotations.

FWIW, I am only able to manifest this issue if I turn on clustering. Also, while the focus of this question was on panning/zooming, I found I was able to reproduce the crash without any panning/zooming. Just was just updating annotations (that participate in clustering) and not touching my device at all, and it eventually crashed with this error. So while it’s easier to manifest with panning/zooming, I think the problem is more fundamental, namely how the map view handles updates to annotations (presumably, only those that may be clustered).

Comment: This is basically what I tried, just without the `target: .main`, adding it still crashes for me after a while